# Is it possible to find the position of a given element in a list without writing a jumble of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to find out the position of a certain element in a list.  In concept, I input an item in the list, and it should return the position of that item.  I have written this:

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

letter = "d" #Want the position in the list of this letter.

for i in range(0, len(alphabet)):
    if alphabet[i] == letter:
        position = i
        break
```

which works, but I feel like there is a more elegant/efficient way of doing it.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: use `index()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
print(alphabet.index('d'))
```

It will return the index of the first 'd' into the list

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had a feeling that python would include something like that, but I wasn't sure where to look.